# Static variable in Laravel Queue Job

Tags: laravel, laravel-queue

Has anyone used static variable in Laravel Queue job?

I need to use static variable to accumulate the incoming file size.

For instance, if the total file size more than 1000mb, I need to make a request to remote server at once.

> ```
> [2017-06-18 07:59:44] local.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'serialize(): "count" returned as member variable from __sleep() but does not exist' in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Queue.php:89
> Stack trace:
>  #0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'serialize(): "a...', 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs...', 89, Array)
> ```

Below is my Queue code.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Jobs\Job;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Log;

class SendToAPI extends Job implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;
    private $data = null;
    private static $count = 0;
    /**
    * Create a new job instance.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function __construct($data)
    {
      $this->data = $data;
    }

    /**
    * Execute the job.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function handle()
    {
       $count = $count + $this->data['file_size'];
       if ($count > 1000)
       {
          // perform action
       }

    } 
 }
```

Comment: "Not working" isn't sufficient information for us to help you.

Comment: sorry sir, i have ammend my post.

Comment: `static` probably won't work as expected because the queue is asynchronous and could occur during subsequent calls

Answer (score 0):

I replicated this issue and got the same error, then searched about it : https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/using-static-variable-in-job-class

This thread concludes that static variables are not serialized.

I suggest that you save the total file size in Redis ( Or any temporary storage ) itself and instead of doing "$count = $count + $this->data['file_size'];" increment the count in Redis and then check the count exceeds the limit.

You can also check out a fix discussed in the thread